# drupal 7 no link in breadcrumb

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, breadcrumbs

I lost links in breadcrumb and guess what, I don't know how. I don't use any form of taxonomy.

here's what I get when for example I'm in context module :

» » » Context

I installed Menu Crumb module to help me find the issue but got no chance except for the added part

can you help me with that ?

PR

Comment: I created a hook in a module that invoke drupal_get_breadcrumb() and things went ok from there

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flushing your caches?

Also, While I'm not familiar with the context module, if it has anything to do with breadcrumbs, it might be conflicting with native the drupal breadcrumbs process